# How to parameterise 4-sphere

Tags: general-topology, geometry, differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

I am wondering if anyone can walk me through how the 4-sphere would be parameterised, and the logic behind the steps. For reference I understand how a sphere is parameterised.

Thank you :)

Comment: It’s worth learning about stereographic projection which avoids trig functions and simplifies many calculations.

Answer (score 1):

We can parameterize the 1-sphere as
$$ x = \cos \theta_1, \\ y = \sin \theta_1,  $$
with $\theta_1 \in [-\pi,\pi)$.
The 2-sphere as
$$ \begin{split} 
x &= \cos \theta_1 &\cos \theta_2, \\ 
y &= \sin \theta_1 &\cos \theta_2, \\ 
z &= &\sin \theta_2 \end{split} $$
with  $\theta_2 \in [-\pi/2,\pi/2]$.
The 3-sphere as
$$ \begin{split} 
x &= \cos \theta_1 &\cos \theta_2 &\cos \theta_3, \\ 
y &= \sin \theta_1 &\cos \theta_2 &\cos \theta_3, \\ 
z &= &\sin \theta_2 &\cos \theta_3 \\
w &= &&\sin \theta_3
\end{split} $$
with  $\theta_3 \in [-\pi/2,\pi/2]$.
The 4-sphere as
$$ \begin{split} 
x &= \cos \theta_1 &\cos \theta_2 &\cos \theta_3 & \cos \theta_4, \\ 
y &= \sin \theta_1 &\cos \theta_2 &\cos \theta_3 & \cos \theta_4, \\ 
z &= &\sin \theta_2 &\cos \theta_3 & \cos \theta_4\\
w &= &&\sin \theta_3 & \cos \theta_4\\
a &= &&&\sin \theta_4
\end{split} $$
with  $\theta_4 \in [-\pi/2,\pi/2]$.

Etc... The only fact you need to know to check that these parameterization indeed work is
$$ \cos(\theta)^2 + \sin(\theta)^2 = 1.$$

Comment: It is worth noting that the logic is the following: at constant height (i.e if the last coordinate is fixed), the intersection of the $(n+1)$-sphere with the horizontal hyperplane is a $n$-sphere whose radius depends on the said height. Hence the apparent inducting process for the parametrization

Comment: What “space” is this? Like what kind of object actually is this? Is this only referring to Euclidean space, or is there a space specifically for parameterisations? When you talk about “fixing the height” what “height” are you referring to in higher dimensions? Is it just a number that satisfies the properties of the “height” in the 1 and 2 cases?

Comment: @Didier is indeed thinking of the spheres embedded in Euclidean space identified with $\mathbb{R}^n$. With "fixing the height" and "horizontal hyperplane" he means setting one of the coordinates to a constant. For example, think of the unit 2-sphere in three dimensional space with coordinates $x,y,z$. Taking the intersection of this 2-sphere and the plane defined by $z=0.5$ (at "height" 0.5) results in a circle.